# Stanford ParserAnnotator doesn't generate annotations

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm beginning to learn the Stanford CoreNLP Java API, and am trying to print the syntax tree of a sentence. The syntax tree is supposed to be generated by the ParserAnnotator. In my code (posted below), the ParserAnnotator runs without errors but doesn't generate anything. The error only shows up when the code tries to get the label of the tree's root node, and the tree is revealed to be null. The components that run before it generate their annotations without any problems.

There was one other person on SO who had a problem with the ParserAnnotator, but the issue was with memory. I've increased the memory that I allow Eclipse to use, but the behavior is the same. Running the code in the debugger also did not yield any errors.

Some background information: The sentence I used was "This is a random sentence." I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String sentence = "This is a random sentence.";
        Annotation doc = initStanford(sentence);
        Tree syntaxTree = doc.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
        printTreePreorder(syntaxTree);
    }
    private static Annotation initStanford(String sentence){
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = pipeline("tokenize, ssplit, parse");
        Annotation document = new Annotation(sentence);
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        return document;
    }
    private static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline(String components){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", components);
        return new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    }
    public static void printTreePreorder(Tree tree){
        System.out.println(tree.label());
        for(int i = 0;i < tree.numChildren();i++){
            printTreePreorder(tree.getChild(i));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the tree off of the document (`Annotation`), rather than the sentences (`CoreMap`). You can get the sentences with:

```
Tree tree = doc.get(SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0).get(TreeAnnotation.class)
```

I can also shamelessly plug the [Simple CoreNLP API](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html):

```
Tree tree = new Sentence("this is a sentence").parse()
```

Comment: Gabor's code just handles the first sentence in a document. A more general pattern is:
`for (CoreMap s : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
    s.get(TreeAnnotation.class).pennPrint();
}`